# LiveData is not updating the View consistently

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

The recycleView isn't updating the result from the network on initial loading.

RecycleView:

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        mRecyclerAdapter = MovieListAdapter(context)

        rvMovieList.apply {
            // Dedicated layouts for Screen Orientation
            if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            } else {
                layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
            }

            adapter = mRecyclerAdapter
        }
    }
```

and listening to the network result using LiveData from ViewModel.

`LiveData` listening snippet the Fragment below:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        // Listen to data change
        viewModel.getMovies().observe(this, mMovieListObserver)
    }

    private val mMovieListObserver: Observer<PagedList<MovieItem>> = Observer { movieItems ->
        Log.d(TAG, "MovieItems: ${movieItems.size}")
        showEmptyList(movieItems?.size == 0)
        mRecyclerAdapter.submitList(movieItems)
    }

    private fun showEmptyList(isEmpty: Boolean) {
        tvEmptyListView.visibility = if (isEmpty) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        rvMovieList.visibility = if (isEmpty) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        viewModel.getMovies().removeObserver(mMovieListObserver)

        super.onPause()
    }
```

The irony is, the result populates the recycleView on subsequent loads. I feel the LiveData isn't working as expected. The expectation while introducing the emptyView was to show/hide the recycleView/EmptyView based on the result from the network.

ViewModel pasted below:

```
class MovieListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val PAGE_SIZE = 10

     internal var movies: LiveData<PagedList<MovieItem>>

    init {
        val dataSourceFactory = MovieDataSourceFactory()

        val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(PAGE_SIZE)
                .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
                .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                .build()

        movies = LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, pagedListConfig)
                // .setBoundaryCallback() TODO
                .build()
    }

    fun getMovies(): LiveData<PagedList<MovieItem>> {
        return movies
    }
}
```

Thanks for the time, appreciate any inputs to the solution or best practices. Thanks.

Repo: https://gitlab.com/faisalm/MovieDirect

////---

Updated the DataSourceFactory and DataSource.

```
class MovieDataSourceFactory : DataSource.Factory<Int, MovieItem>() {

    private val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<MovieDataSource>()

    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, MovieItem> {
        val dataSource = MovieDataSource()
        mutableLiveData.postValue(dataSource)
        return dataSource
    }
}
```

---

```
class MovieDataSource internal constructor() : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, MovieItem>() {

    private val movieDbService: MovieDbService = RetrofitFactory.create()

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, MovieItem>) {

        val moviesListCall = movieDbService.fetchLatestMoviesPaged(Constants.API_KEY, 1)
        moviesListCall.enqueue(object : Callback<MoviesList> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MoviesList>, response: Response<MoviesList>) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val moviesLists = response.body()?.results
                    callback.onResult(moviesLists!!, 1, 2)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MoviesList>, t: Throwable) {}
        })
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, MovieItem>) {}

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, MovieItem>) {

        val moviesListCall = movieDbService.fetchLatestMoviesPaged(Constants.API_KEY, params.key)

        moviesListCall.enqueue(object : Callback<MoviesList> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<MoviesList>, response: Response<MoviesList>) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val moviesLists = response.body()?.results
                    callback.onResult(moviesLists!!, params.key + 1)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MoviesList>, t: Throwable) {}
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the result populates the recycleView on subsequent loads"?

Comment: Do you notified adapter about `mRecyclerAdapter.submitList(movieItems)` data changes? *(Something like `notifyDataSetChanged` or something better)*?

Comment: @JeelVankhede no need there for that because he is using a PagedList<T>

Comment: Are you getting any errors, perhaps that would be nice if you post your DataSource class?

Comment: @RahulShukla though the result isn't reflecting in the initial load, the list is populated once User goes home/out of the app and come back.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the way you're adding and removing the observer for the liveData.

Instead of adding in `onResume` and removing in `onPause`, just observe it in `onActivityCreated` in the Fragment. LiveData's observe method takes in a LifeCycleOwner (which is what you're passing with `this` in the Fragment), and it'll take care of making sure it's observing at the correct time in that lifecycle.

So remove these lines:

`viewModel.getMovies().removeObserver(mMovieListObserver)` `viewModel.getMovies().addObserver(this, mMovieListObserver)`

and add this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.getMovies().observe(this, Observer { movieItems ->
        Log.d(TAG, "MovieItems: ${movieItems.size}")
        showEmptyList(movieItems?.loadedCount == 0)
        mRecyclerAdapter.submitList(movieItems)
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I tried this option before and didn't work.


Found the `movieItems.size` is stubborn though the observer emits the updated value once received from the remote. Commenting `showEmptyList()` results as expected with updated values.


Strongly feel empty list handling should be revisited.

Comment: It could have something to do with using `movieItems?.size` vs `movieItems?.loadedCount` (size is loaded count + placeholder count, I believe), but it looks like the correct way of implementing an empty view is using the `LivePagedListBuilder.setBoundaryCallback`? It could be that internally, if the view is hidden then it is considered as "not observable". Another fix would be to have the `rvMovieList` stay visible, only changing the visibility of `tvEmptyListView`

Comment: In that case, showEmptyList should look like this:

    private fun showEmptyList(isEmpty: Boolean) { 
        tvEmptyListView.visibility = if (isEmpty) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }